# in the ASPxGridView How to change label's text on focused row change?

Tags: asp.net

i use code to change lable text in the Focused row changed from serverside.
my code on the ASP.net created project is :

```
protected void gvCuentas_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   /string Cuenta;
    int Indice;


    //Se llena el indice segun la fila que seleccionen en el grid
    Indice = gvCuentas.FocusedRowIndex;


    //Se evalua si no ha seleccionado ninguna que deje el idice en 1
    if (Indice == -1)
    {
        Indice = 1;
    }


    //Se captura el id de la cuenta seleccionada
    Cuenta = gvCuentas.GetRowValues(Indice, gvCuentas.KeyFieldName).ToString();


    lblTituloDetalle.Text = Cuenta;


}
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you implement following scenario instead to use your code in client side:

1. Handle the **client-side ASPxClientGridView.FocusedRowChanged** event;
2. Call the **ASPxClientLabel.SetText** method to set its value in this event handler. Use the **ASPxClientGridView.GetFocusedRowIndex** method to obtain the focused row index.